# ST600 Rechargable batteries problems

Tags: soundtrap

Our RA in the field is deploying Soundtrap ST600s with the recommended Panasonic 18650 batteries that Ocean Instruments recommends (not easy to get hold of). She has charged the batteries fully, but when she puts them in the Soundtrap it is saying they are only 55/58% charged.

Has anyone else had this problem, &/or can recommend a solution? For now we are assuming she just deploys with all 12 batteries and hope it lasts for a reasonable amount of time. But this deployment is in a very remote location so we need it to last as long as possible as retrieving it may be in many months time.

Many thanks in advance
Clare

Comment: have soundtrap or batteries been tested before?

Comment: No, first outing! I've used other soundtraps before but this is the first time using ST600.

Comment: I don't have any advice but I am currently sourcing some batteries for ST600s and would be curious where you got yours (to maybe avoid those ones?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the batteries have not been tested before, it is very likely that the quality of the batteries that "not easy to get hold of" as you say, are of bad quality, already used etc. Happens frequently. I would consider to recover recorders at half the planned time.

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't already seen it, check the soundtrap endurance calculator [here](http://www.oceaninstruments.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/SoundTrap-Endurance-Calculator.xlsx).

Hopefully this can be helpful in adjusting your deployment time.